# Prime factor in javascript, why is this case not working?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, primes

I'm writing a primality checker in in j/s and I was wondering why I'm getting true as a return for when I test 55... It seems to work fine for all the other cases I checked just not 55, can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
var isPrime = function(num){

    if (num === 2){
        return true;
    }
    else if(num%2 === 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        var i = 2;
        while(i<num){

            if((num/i) % i === 0 ){
                return false;
            }
                i++
        }
        return true;
    }

};
```

Thanks in advance and apologies for the noobness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       if((num/i) % i === 0 ){
            return false;
       }
```

What is this case?
Shouldn't it be

```
       if(num % i === 0 ){
            return false;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Andrey pointed out, your `if` statement inside the `while` loop is not correct. For 55 at `i=5` you should get false for 55 being prime, but `55/5 % 5 == 1` Also you could use just `==` instead of `===` for logical equals, since `===` checks if both values and type are equal, which is not necessary here.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for pointing that out, must have misread something on code academy, lol.

Comment: lol no worries. I didn't even know there was a `===` logical operator in JavaScript, so I checked it out on w3 schools and read that it was very similiar to `==`, but also checks object type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var isPrime = function isPrime(value) {
    var i = 2;
    for(i; i < value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return value > 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your bug may be solved, I'd recommend to think about some other aspects to optimize your code:

1. Clarify your corner cases: In the beginning, check for n<2 -> return false. At least to math theory primes are defined as natural number larger then 1, so 1 is by definition not a prime like all the negative numbers. Your code won't handle negative numbers correctly.
2. You don't have to check all divisors up to n-1. You can obviously stop checking at n/2, but there are even proofs for tighter bounds which means you can stop checking already at √n if I'm right. To further optimize, you don't have to check even divisors >2.

   ```
   else {
     var i = 3;
     while ( i < num/2 ) {
       if( num % i == 0 ) {
           return false;
       }
       i+=2;
     }
     return true;
   }
   ```

   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test for details about testing of primes.

P.S: I just wrote the code here in the text box, but it looks like it might work.